# How can I compensate for soft white ceiling lights adding warmth to the light coming from a big window?

Tags: lighting, white-balance

[image]I have 12 overhead soft white canned lights in a 10ft ceiling, each casting about 65watts.

A large tinted window is bringing a ton of grey light into a 550 ft room.

So my problem is now the can lights are warming up the grey turning people orange, and the grey natural light I can't warm up so photos look blueish.

What kind of stationary lighting do I need to cancel that grey? How many? Wattage?

Thank you.

Comment: Cover the window with black curtains, or at least a black liner.

Comment: what on earth is grey light?!

Comment: Can you post example photos? Ideally, both of the room and of the result you're getting?

Comment: The grey light is the result of natural light coming in through the tinted window. So my pics turn out cold blue and people turn out either blue or orange.  Very hard to correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have incandescent bulbs in the cans, you can gel them with [Full Blue CTB](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/44119-REG/Rosco_RS320211_3202_Full_Blue.html) to convert them to a color temperature that more closely resembles daylight.

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed lighting.

You can replace the ceiling can lights to match the color temp of the lighting coming thru the windows.

Or you can bring in studio strobes and gel them to match the ambient coming in thru the window.

Then you set your camera WB to the color of light coming in thru the window.

Do NOT assume the light from your windows is at 5000k as you have tinted windows.  You need to actually find out what the color tint is so you can balance to it.  It could be much cooler than 5000k.

Also note: Unless your windows face north and are sheltered from direct sunlight at all times of the day the color tint of the light coming thru the window may change during the course of the day.

Instead of fighting the mixed lighting, you may want to use it for a special effect.  If you color balance to your interior lighting you can let the window lighting act as a blue "rim light" for atmosphere.

I recommend reading the Lighting 101 and Lighting 102 tutorials on Strobist:

http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101.html
http://strobist.blogspot.com/2007/06/lighting-102-introduction.html

To learn more about mixed lighting and what options you have to either "fix" or "utilize" it.

Answer (score 2):

One easy option is to replace the overhead bulbs with 5000K CFL bulbs to match the natural light from the window.

Comment: These pics were taken with a point and shoot.  Im getting a canon 70d with a 10-22 lens so I can take better shots for social media and shoot in house videos.  I didn't buy a flash or lighting yet because I want to figure this issue out first.